# Branche diff results different in stash

Tags: git, git-diff

I am trying to diff two branches in Stash, for example branch A & B, and noticed that if diff the branches in the sequence of comparing branch A with branch B, and then reverse it, compare branch B with branch A, the diff results are different, which does not make sense. any thoughts about why it happens ?

Answer (score 0):

The diff is not always from the exact same starting point in each branch:
The 'git diff' between branches might compare the tips only OR the changes since one branch was made from the other
e.g.

```
git diff A B    // Changes between tips of 'A' and 'B' branches.
git diff A...B  // Changes that occurred on 'B' since when the 'A' was started off it
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan. still not quite clear,  from my understanding, the modified file list should be identical no matter how we issue the git diff command line, git diff A B or git diff B A, but actually the outputs I get are totally different which is really strange. sorry, just a new user for git/stash.

Comment: True, content of files should be identical (if you just created the branch and did not change their content) - you can compare each file this way : git diff branch1:file branch2:file and it should be the same. However,if you compare branches as a whole, you are not only comparing files' content but also more stuff underneath : commits history, tags, SHA-1s signatures, etc.... and these are NOT identical.
Regardless of the issue here - if U wanna pick under the hood a bit : http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html